# Place Autocomplete Error while autocompleting: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

When I try to search at Place Autocomplete I got **Can't Load Search Results**
and the logs say

> "Error while autocompleting: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"

I have enabled https://console.cloud.google.com/ 
and API key works well.

[image]

**Java Code**

```
    String apiKey = "MY API KEY";
    private RadioGroup mRadioGroup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_costumer_map);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), apiKey);

        PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);
          // Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment.
        AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

        // Specify the types of place data to return.
        autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));

        // Set up a PlaceSelectionListener to handle the response.
        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                destination = place.getName().toString();
                destinationLatLng = place.getLatLng();

                Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onError: " + status);
            }
        });
```

**XML Code**

```
       <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_margin="20sp">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
            android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are getting OVER_QUERY_LIMIT message **because you have not enabled billing for your project** in [developers console](https://console.developers.google.com).

> To use the Places SDK for Android, you must include an [API key](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/signup) with all API requests and you must [enable billing](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable?redirect=https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/usage-and-billing?dialogOnLoad%3Dbilling-enabled&_ga=2.182998947.461830153.1550562032-1721692727.1545130792) on each of your projects.

Check [this link](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/usage-and-billing#top_of_page) for more info and pricing.

**SKU: Basic Data**

> Fields in the Basic category are included in the base cost of the Places request, and do not result in any additional charge. The Basic Data SKU is triggered when any of these fields are requested: ADDRESS, ID, LAT_LNG, NAME, OPENING_HOURS, PHOTO_METADATAS, PLUS_CODE, TYPES, USER_RATINGS_TOTAL, VIEWPORT.

You can check pricing and other SKUs in the [same link](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/usage-and-billing#data-skus) given above.

Comment: Man, this is tough, anything regarding billling 

Answer (score 2):

`OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` indicates that you are over your quota.
The main reason is:

> If you exceed the usage limits you will get an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT status code as a response.
>
> This means that the web service will stop providing normal responses and switch to returning only status code OVER_QUERY_LIMIT until more usage is allowed again. This can happen:
>
> 1. Within a few seconds, if the error was received because your application sent too many requests per second.
> 2. Within the next 24 hours, if the error was received because your application sent too many requests per day. The daily quotas are reset at midnight, Pacific Time.

You can also check this for more details: https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/articles/usage-limits

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but i cant use it from the first day i made it how can i use my limit

Comment: For increasing uses limit you need to have a paid account. you have to pay for updating limit.

Comment: Thats Bad :( , Thanks For Your Help ^_^

Comment: For more you can also check this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/usage-and-billing

Answer (score 0):

You will receive an `PLACES_API_RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED` error if you are using the now deprecated Play Services  version of the Places SDK `com.google.android.gms:play-services-places` as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/usage-and-billing?dialogOnLoad=billing-enabled&folder&organizationId):

> Notice: If your Android app is experiencing 9005 PLACES_API_RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED errors, you may be using a deprecated version of the Places SDK for Android. The Google Play Services version of the Places SDK for Android (for example com.google.android.gms:play-services- places) was deprecated as of January 29, 2019, and was turned off on July 29, 2019. A new version of the Places SDK for Android is now available. We recommend updating to the new version as soon as possible. For details, see the migration guide.

You must replace the following line in your `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:<VERSION>'
```

With:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.2.0'
```

Note that version 2 or greater requires androidx. At the time of writing the latest version that does not required androidx is 1.1.0.